# How to insert image over image in GD library in php?

Tags: php

I want to create a certificate using GD Library but I'm unable to do this I tried so many ways to do this tired lot of stack overflow solution but unable to achieve what I want.

I take image from user and move it to an folder and now I want to fetch it while generating certificate but only text is appearing not image and anyone also help me with how to set the image width which I insert as student photo.

Here it is what I tried :

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



// student photo
$iname = $_FILES["stphoto"] ["name"];
$tname = $_FILES["stphoto"] ["tmp_name"];
$stfld = "certificate/".$iname;
move_uploaded_file($tname,$stfld);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('content-type:image/jpeg');

$font=realpath('arial.ttf');

$image=imagecreatefromjpeg("certificate/shivam.jpeg");
$color=imagecolorallocate($image,19,21,22);
// enroll

$en="Er. No.SCC/ ";
imagettftext($image,18,0,90,260,$color,$font,$en);


$enroll=$_POST['enroll'];
imagettftext($image,19,0,225,260,$color,$font,$enroll);

// name
$name=$_POST['name'];
imagettftext($image,29,0,365,420,$color,$font,$name);


// student image
//student photo
$repst = imageCreateFromjpeg($stfld);
imagecopymerge($image, $repst, 940, 122, 0, 0, 118, 147, 100);

imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="number" name="enroll">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <!-- <input type="text" name="sof">
    <input type="text" name="type">
    <input type="date" name="sdate">
    <input type="date" name="edate"> -->
    <input type="file" name="stphoto">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: And if you use only this code `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("certificate/shivam.jpeg");
$repst = imageCreateFromjpeg($stfld);

imagecopymerge($image, $repst, 940, 122, 0, 0, 118, 147, 100);

imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image)`

You have yours images...?

Comment: @Juan yes.when form submitted my image move to certificate folder.

Comment: @Juan what should i do? to achieve it !

Comment: @Juan but image is uploaded by user to the form.

Comment: You have a user uploaded image represented by "$stfld". And you have an image already present on the disk represented by "$image"...? And when you use this simple code above you have your two images in one....?

Comment: @Juan yeah because I want to upload image over my last image

Comment: If you change the last parameter of merge function...? Do you see image appear...? With 50 instead of 100 for example...

Comment: ..???? No more news... ? No answers...? No following...?

Comment: @Juan it doesn't work so I tried some other ways to do this. like using javascript

Comment: There is no image appear when you change the last parameter on merge function..?